# Graphviz - define the order of the clusters

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm generating clustered nodes in graphviz/dot. Simplified example:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR

    n2a->n3
    n1->n2b
    n2b->n2a
    n2b->n3
    n3->n1

    subgraph cluster_1 { label="cluster_1" n1 }
    subgraph cluster_2 { label="cluster_2" n2a n2b }
    subgraph cluster_3 { label="cluster_3" n3 }
}
```

[image]

I want to force dot to always put the clusters in ascending order from right to left (cluster 1 in the left, next is cluster 2 etc.), but to arrange the nodes inside each cluster as dot dictates automatically.

I tried to play with `clusterrank`, `rank`, `newrank`, `constraint=false` and couldn't manage to make it happen. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "force" this to happen by adding edges to establish rank of every node in every cluster.  Every node in cluster_1 has a lesser rank than every node in cluster_2, etc.  Like so:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR

    n2a->n3
    n1->n2b
    n2b->n2a
    n2b->n3
    n3->n1

    subgraph cluster_1 { label="cluster_1" n1 }
    subgraph cluster_2 { label="cluster_2" n2a n2b }
    subgraph cluster_3 { label="cluster_3" n3 }
    // simple-minded solution - force clusters based on (added) rank
    edge [style=invis]
    {n1} -> {n2a n2b} -> {n3}
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! :) In the real graph (that has many back-arrows) it didn't work at first. I needed to add `edge[weight=0]` or `edge[weight=1]` before the regular-edges, and `edge[style=invis,weight=2]` before the cluster-organizing-edges. It's not totally perfect (they go diagonally for some reason), but it is indeed from left to right.